# Diferencia entre el tipo de dato serial y secuencia en Postgresql

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Estoy creando una base de datos en Postgresql y me surgio una duda. ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre el tipo de dato serial y crear una secuencia? ¿Alguna de las dos es mejor para cuando se tiene grandes cantidades de datos almacenados y se quieren recuperar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SERIAL` es un seudo tipo. Cuando se define una columna `SERIAL`, pasa lo siguiente:

- Crea una secuencia y fija el valor next como el default value para la
  columna.
- Añade un constraint NOT NULL a la columna porque la secuencia siempre generará un entero.
- Asigna como dueño de la secuencia a la columna que la usa; por esto, la secuencia  se elimina si la columna o la tabla pasan por un
  DROP.

Son pues, equivalentes, sólo que SERIAL a) no es SQL estándar, y b) realiza algunas validaciones adicionales en la creación/eliminación de la columna que ya puedes ver. A la hora de usar SERIAL o una secuencia, en desempeño no habrá, pues, ninguna diferencia.

En la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html) se especifica esto así:

> The data types serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a
>   notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar
>   to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases). In
>   the current implementation, specifying:
>
> `CREATE TABLE tablename (
>       colname SERIAL );`
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> `CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;`
>
> `CREATE TABLE tablename (
>       colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq') );`
>
> `ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;`
>
> Thus, we have created an integer column and arranged for its default
>   values to be assigned from a sequence generator. A NOT NULL constraint
>   is applied to ensure that a null value cannot be inserted. (In most
>   cases you would also want to attach a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   to prevent duplicate values from being inserted by accident, but this
>   is not automatic.) Lastly, the sequence is marked as "owned by" the
>   column, so that it will be dropped if the column or table is dropped.

Por último, recuerda que hay varios seudo tipos SERIAL: smallserial, serial y bigserial, que varían en el número de bits usados (y por tanto, en el valor máximo/mínimo soportado).

Answer (score 1):

Una expliacion mas simple
en teoría son casi parecidos su principales diferencias 
**SERIAL**:aumenta de 1 en 1 (no especificamos nada) 
ejemplo :

```
introducir create table libros( codigo serial , autor varchar(30)primary key codigo));
```

**SEQUENCE**: con esto logramos especifiar si aumentara de x en x incluso ponemos limites a hasta b

```
 create sequence sec_codigolibros  start with 1  increment by 1 maxvalue 99999 minvalue 1;
```

esta es una simple explicacion si quieres ir mas fondo lee esto [serial](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/postgresqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?inicio=0&cod=171&punto=13) [sequence](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/postgresqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?inicio=50&cod=228&punto=70)